# Custom Transition Not Being Called

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift, I have a custom transition which I'm trying to do which is.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomPushAnimation: NSObjectUIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.2
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let containerVw = transitionContext.containerView
        let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)
        guard let fromVc = fromViewController, let toVc = toViewController else { return }
        let finalFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toVc)

        //For different animation you can play around this line by changing frame
        toVc.view.frame = finalFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: finalFrame.size.height/2)
        containerVw.addSubview(toVc.view)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
            toVc.view.frame = finalFrame
            fromVc.view.alpha = 0.5
        }, completion: {(finished) in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(finished)
            fromVc.view.alpha = 1.0
        })
    }
}
```

And then in the the home view controller I have a button called settings and I have done this

```
lazy var customPushAnimation: CustomPushAnimation = {
    return CustomPushAnimation()
}()

func openViewController() {
    let vc = SettingsViewController()
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    navigationController.transitioningDelegate = self.customPushAnimation
    present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then I also have this extension:

```
extension ViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return customPushAnimation
    }
}
```

And then when the button is clicked the openViewController function is called and the view controller I want to open would be presented using the custom animation I have. Instead I just keep getting the standard sliding animation that you have when using a show segue in a navigation controller.

Comment: `navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom`. Add it

Comment: Where should I put that code, I tried it in the openViewController function,  but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: It should be in the openViewController method. Moreover, you are setting the transitioningDelegate to an instance variable (customPushAnimation), not the ViewController. Since in the extension is for the ViewController, the transitioningDelegate should be set as self.